# mv filename .. (Where will the file go?)

Tags: rename

```
[root@localhost /home/chankey/Desktop/Downloads]# ls
myproject.plx
[root@localhost /home/chankey/Desktop/Downloads]# mv myproject.plx ..
```

I had the file in Downloads folder. I used mv command as shown above and now I can't see the file. It is neither in the Desktop folder nor in the Downloads.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if `/home/chankey/Desktop/Download` for some reason would be a symlink to for example `/home/chankey/Download` ...  If so, it may be that that the file is in `/home/chankey/`

Comment: Yes the file was in /home/chankey/

Answer (score 6):

The move command you show using `..` as the target will move your file UP one directory to `/home/chankey/Desktop/myproject.plx`. The `..` folder syntax is always the parent folder.

If it's not there, you did something different than you are showing. Perhaps you typed in three dots and it actually got named that: `/home/chankey/Desktop/Downloads/...`

Comment: Caleb is correct.  If your history is enabled, you can confirm the command you issued by checking it.  Simply issue the `history` command at the prompt.

Comment: You can use `history -n 100` to see more history lines...